# res.view() changes static asset path

Tags: sails.js

When using res.view('reset') all of the static assets (IE css and js files) are prefixed with reset.

Example:

www.myapp.com/reset/angular.min.js <-- Incorrect

www.myapp.com/angular.min.js <-- correct

I have the following controller:

```
reset: function (req, res) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: new Date(Date.now()) } }, function (err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      res.notFound();
      return res.backToLoginPage();
    }
    return res.view('reset')
  });
}
```

Naturally, sails is responding with 404's because none of the assets live at that path.

How do I get the res.view('reset') to serve the files from the same directory as when specifying the view from a route like 'GET /reset': {view: 'reset'}?

Comment: What is your controller name?

Comment: What does the actual `<script>` tag in your HTML look like?  Sounds like you just have a relative path for the `src` instead of an absolute path (starting with `/`).

Comment: You are correct, the assets were not prefixed with `/ ` DOH